# Slick not adapting responsively

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I have a `div` which houses 5 child `divs`.

- On breakpoints `1199px` and below, I don't want `slick slider` to initiate.
- On breakpoints between `1200px` and `1599px`, I want `slick slider` to show 2 slides.
- On breakpoints between `1600p` and 1919px`, I want` slick slider` to show 3 slides.
- On breakpoints `1920px` and above, I don't want `slick slider` to initiate (so it shows all 5 cards).

However, when resizing the window up and down, the slider doesn't showcase the defined slides for that breakpoint.

Approach:

```js
$(function() {

  const table_slider = $("#table");

  const settings = {
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    mobileFirst: true,
    initialSlide: 1,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1599,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1919,
        settings: 'unslick'
      }
    ]
  };

  $(pricing_table_slider).slick(settings);

  if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
    $(pricing_table_slider).slick('unslick');
  }

  $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
    $(pricing_table_slider).slick('resize');
  });

  $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1199 && $(window).width() < 1919) {
      $(pricing_table_slider).slick('resize');
    } else{
      $(pricing_table_slider).slick('unslick');
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="table">
  <div class="card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="card">Card 4</div>
  <div class="card">Card 5</div>
</div>
```

Edit:

Have edited snippet, with the above JS, slick doesn't init when resizing window above 1200px.

Comment: What's question exactly?

Comment: Why slick isn't adapting according to the settings defined.